# Sharing a printer over the net from Windows 7 to Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, windows-7, print-server, shared-printers

I need to share a printer that is connected to a Windows 7 computer. The windows 7 computer is in another building about an hours drive away.

The computer that needs to access the printer is running Windows Server 2008.

Ive tried setting the printer as 'shared' for 'everyone' on the Windows 7 PC and accessing it from the server by adding a TCP/IP port to the IP address but the printer just wont add.

From googling aparently it may need setting up as a printer server through IIS, but i'm just not sure on the best practice.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Grant Unwin

Answer (score 1):

Can you establish a VPN connection between the two machines (even a free solution like Hamachi should work)? Then you can just share the printer the normal way and the communication will be secured...